# Nested elements with List is null with ResponseEntity in Spring

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a REST Controller as follows using Spring boot 1.3.5 and Java 8. This works perfect while testing with Advanced REST Client (**ARC**) Utility - send xml request and returns the expected xml response as shown right below this controller code.

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/rateQuote")
public class RateQuoteController {

     @Autowired
     private RateQuotingService rateQuotingService;           

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json","application/xml"}, produces = {"application/json","application/xml"})
     public ResponseEntity<RateQuoteDto> getRateQuote(@RequestBody RESTRequestDto request){                              
            RateQuoteDto rateQuoteDto = rateQuotingService.getRateQuote(request.getStateCode(), request.getZipCode(), request.getClient(), request.getThreshold(),
                    benefit,request.getLob(), localEffectiveDate);
            return (new ResponseEntity<>(rateQuoteDto, HttpStatus.OK));
     }    
}
```

Request with **ARC**-

url - `http://localhost:8080/rateQuote`

Method - `POST`

Headers -

```
Content-Type: application/xml   
Accept: application/xml
```

Request Body -

```
<request>
    <stateCode>NY</stateCode>
    <zipCode>10005</zipCode>
    <client>BMG</client>
    <threshold>1000</threshold>
    <lob>PDI</lob>
    <benefitLevel>15000</benefitLevel>
    <effectiveDate>2016-01-01</effectiveDate>
</request
```

Response -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rateQuote>
   <status>Approve</status>
   <message>Quote is successfully retrieved.</message>
   <quote>
      <threshold1 amount="1000">
         <benefits>
            <benefitLevel amount="15000">
               <annualPremium>990.00</annualPremium>
               <semiAnnualPremium>440.00</semiAnnualPremium>
               <quaterlyPremium>200.00</quaterlyPremium>
               <monthlyPremium>77.00</monthlyPremium>
            </benefitLevel>
         </benefits>
      </threshold1>
   </quote>
</rateQuote>
```

So far so good. However, I have an issue with response when call is made grammatically.And the issue is that the most of the response's nodes are null as shown below:

```
    @Test
    public void getQuote()throws Exception{
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        //RESTRequestDto   is JAXB decorated
        RESTRequestDto  body = new RESTRequestDto();
        body.setStateCode("NY");
        body.setZipCode("10005");
        body.setClient("BMG");
        body.setThreshold("1000");
        body.setLob("PDI");
        body.setBenefitLevel("15000");
        body.setEffectiveDate(DateUtils.createDate("2016-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd"));


        RequestEntity<RESTRequestDto> request = RequestEntity.post(new URI("http://localhost:8080/rateQuote"))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(body);
        ResponseEntity<RateQuoteDto> response = template.exchange(request, RateQuoteDto.class);
        RateQuoteDto rateQuote = response.getBody();

        System.out.println(rateQuote);
    }
```

**Response** -

```
RateQuoteDto{status=Approve, message=Quote is successfully retrieved., zipCode=null, clientId=null, quote=QuoteDto{threshold1=ThresholdDto{amount=1000, benefitLevelLst=null}}}
```

However, changing the Media Type to JSON works as shown below:

```
   RequestEntity<RESTRequestDto> request = RequestEntity.post(new URI("http://localhost:8080/rateQuote"))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(body);
```

**Response** -

```
RateQuoteDto{status=Approve, message=Quote is successfully retrieved., zipCode=10005, clientId=BMG, quote=QuoteDto{threshold1=ThresholdDto{amount=1000, benefitLevelLst=[BenefitDto{amount=15000, annualPremium=990.00, semiAnnualPremium=440.00, quaterlyPremium=200.00, monthlyPremium=77.00}]}}}
```

**Observation** - 
As shown below, the ist benefitLevelLst is not bound with **MediaType.XML** returning null value show above but works just fine with **MediaType.JSON**. Any idea as to why?

```
public class ThresholdDto {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String amount;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "benefits")
    @XmlElement(name = "benefitLevel")
    private List<BenefitDto> benefitLevelLst;

    . . .
}
```